# How to view webpages offline

Tags: android, html, offline

can i embed webpages in my app?

I need to view certain webpages of my company that is save to the app.

My app needs to access certain webpages in my company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Just add a WebView to your layout and have it load the html from a file locally (either on disk or in assets).  This is assuming you don't want to download updates-  if you do you need to cache the files locally then load them in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a Service to download the pages when a connection is detected and cache them as local files on the device.